# Config file in Node.js distributable package

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue.js

I've been told to implement Continuous Integration for an existing application (FrontEnd: Node.js - BackEnd: .Net API).

The API endpoints are currently hardcoded in the .js files, that get "uglyfied" after the build (webpack). I want to move them to a config file, that gets copied to the dist folder, so they can be changed at deployment time (just like a Web.config file in the API).

I have zero experience with Node. Is this possible? How?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Comment: I tried with the config module but when I use it I get a lot of "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xxx'... " errors. Then my lack of knowledge gets in the way :(

Answer (score 1):

Look into a `dotenv` file and use process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE in your code to access environment variables. Here's one library https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv but I'm sure there others (can't remember which one I used in the past).

**Edit:** If you're using Webpack to bundle your front end app you might need to configure it to pull in environment variables, you can use the define plugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: Looks promising, but It fails to load the variables. This should be simple, it´s so frustrating.